# ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column '“CompanyA”' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, quotes

I'm not sure why im getting this error. ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column '“CompanyA”' in 'field list'.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `company`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `company` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

INSERT INTO `company` (`id`, `name`) VALUES (1, “CompanyA”);
INSERT INTO `company` (`id`, `name`) VALUES (2, “CompanyB”);
```

Comment: It looks like the problem is your quote marks in `“CompanyA”` and `“CompanyB”` Use the standard `'` quote marks instead.

Comment: @ObsidianAge that gives me this error: `ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column '‘CompanyA’' in 'field list'`

Comment: Hi. You have problems with quotes. Google the manual and read about quotes. Use unicode quotes (`'` & `"`) not smart quotes. Google your error message without your particular names/strings and read many answers. Read [ask] & the downvote arrow mouseover text.

Answer (score 1):

Use single-quotes for string literals and date literals.

```
INSERT INTO `company` (`id`, `name`) VALUES (1, 'CompanyA');
```

Double-quotes are treated the same as single-quotes in MySQL by default, but if you set the SQL mode of `ANSI` or `ANSI_QUOTES`, double-quotes are treated as identifier delimiters, the same as back-ticks.

Do not use smart-quotes of any kind:

```
“CompanyA”
‘CompanyA’
```

The examples above use smart-quotes, these are different from both single-quotes and double-quotes.

If you are using a code editor that is replacing straight-quotes with smart-quotes, you need to disable that editor feature. I don't know any programming language that works well with smart-quotes.

For more information, read:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html